# measuring analog current output with beaglebone

Tags: sensor, 4-20ma, flow-sensor

I'm thinking about using a BeagleBone to measure the flow-rate of a fluid through a pipe. Here is a breakdown of the scenario:

- this [flow sensor](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/Shopping/Catalog/Process_Control_-a-_Measurement/Flow_Sensors/Flow_Transmitters/FSA1-42-27H) could be used

  - from the doc, the output is a 4-20 mA analog current
  - the doc claims there is short-circuit protection (not sure if I know exactly what that means)
- the BeagleBone has a 1.8 V max analog input for its ADC, and supposedly sources 2 µA per pin

Does this mean if I wire less than a 90 Ω resistor (1.8 V / .02 A = 90 Ω) between the sensor ground and output, I am good to measure the voltage across that load without fear of damaging the BeagleBone analog input?

Is it that simple, or am I missing some details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it would work. Since the maximum load as given in the spec sheet is 500 Ω, something about 20% of that should work.

So, there's the [E-series of preferred numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-series_of_preferred_numbers), and easily available resistors usually are in that. In your case, something close to, but a little less then 90 Ω would be perfect – so maybe 82 Ω, but more likely the common 68 Ω value. Make sure to buy resistors with a low tolerance!